# React bind custom handler onChange to input

Tags: reactjs

This is my **SearchForm.js**, it creates form with two inputs `keywords` and `city` and select list `date`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       keywords: '',
       city: '',
       date: ''     
      }

      //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        
      this.handleKeywordsChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
     }
    
    handleKeywordsChange(event) {
        console.log(1);
    }
    
    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='form search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Keywords" onChange={this.handleKeywordsChange} value={this.state.name} />

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} />
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="date">Date</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="date" id="date" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-row">
                     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input id='formButton' className='btn btn-primary' type='submit' placeholder='Send' />
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm }
```

and I need to add different handle function to inputs like `handleKeywordsChange`, but there are some errors
[image]

What's wrong with my `bind` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in

```
this.handleKeywordsChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
```

Have you tried change it to

```
this.handleKeywordsChange = this.handleKeywordsChange.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is because of this:

```
this.handleKeywordsChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
```

You need to define `handleInputChange`, instead of `handleKeywordsChange`:

```
handleInputChange () {

}
```

Reason is as per [**MDN Doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So in `handleKeywordsChange` method you are just storing the reference of function returned by bind. So the actual function will be `handleInputChange` and that you need to define.